# Enable an image on a selected table row

Tags: ios, swift, tableview

I have tableview with prototype cells which has 2 labels and image on the right side.
currently if I have let say 10 rows of data, I see the image on each row. however I want to only see the image on a selected row and not all of them.
So as soon as I select a row, I want  the image to appear
Can someone guid me as how to accomplish this in Swift?
I am thinking maybe initially I can disable it in the attributes inspector and once a row is selected enable it for that row only, not not sure how to do that.

[image]

Comment: You need to select only one row at a time? or if you select one row then its image enable and then if u select other then that row image is also enable?

Answer (score 0):

You can implement below code to achieve that

```
@implement CustomCell

- (void)awakeFromNib {
    [super awakeFromNib];
[_imagevw setHidden:YES];
[_imageTopConstraint setActive:NO];
[_imageBottomConstraint setActive:NO];
}

- (void)setHighlighted:(BOOL)highlighted animated:(BOOL)animated{
[_imageTopConstraint setActive:YES];
[_imageBottomConstraint setActive:YES];
}  

@end
```

Above line would do the trick if all set properly .

Your tableview `rowHeight` should be `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` and `estimatedRowHeight` with default value

Comment: Thanks, would you give me the swift version of this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this one swift code for solving your problem :

```
override func awakeFromNib() {
   super.awakeFromNib()
   imagevw.hidden = true
   imageTopConstraint.active = false
   imageBottomConstraint.active = false
}

func setHighlighted(highlighted: Bool, animated: Bool) {
   imageTopConstraint.active = true
   imageBottomConstraint.active = true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this is a swift version of very good  @iDev's Solution

```
override func awakeFromNib() {
super.awakeFromNib()
imagevw.hidden = true
imageTopConstraint.active = false
imageBottomConstraint.active = false
}

 func setHighlighted(highlighted: Bool, animated: Bool) {
imageTopConstraint.active = true
imageBottomConstraint.active = true
imagevw.hidden = false

}
```

For that you need to take IBOutlet for Top Constraint , Bottom Constraint of imageview in your custom cell